# php exec tar call fails when run via cron, works via shell

Tags: php, exec, tar

Can anyone explain why this line works when called from shell, but fails when called via crontab?

```
passthru("tar xvf $file $tarfile/application $tarfile/application_detail $tarfile/application_device_type $tarfile/genre_application");
}
```

The error I got emailed after cron was

> tar: itunes20100907/application:
>   Cannot open: No such file or directory
>   itunes20100907/application_detail

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you must be in the wrong directory. You should use the canonical path.

---

> **Note:** When [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) is enabled, you can only execute files within the [safe_mode_exec_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir). For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable.

Comment: And you can use the `getcwd()` function in PHP to find out what path your script is running from. In the case of the cron job, it's probably the cron user's home folder. If it's, say, /home/ubuntu/, then the path itunes20100907/application would be interpreted as /home/ubuntu/itunes20100907/application